# googleplus integration for Android

Tags: android, google-plus, sha1, google-api-console

Am trying to integrate google plus on existing android app . Have created google api console project at https://code.google.com/apis/console/ .Now as this link says https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android we need to  "**Create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID**" ,after creating  it gives an error message as "**This client ID is globally unique and is already in use**" .May be its saying i cant used same SHA1 key but, need to use same key for all the google API's. Thanks

**Solution**:

Deleted debug.keystore from android folder (users--->.android--->debug.keystore), then run the app and a new key store will be generated ,generate SHA1 from that key store and problem is solved.Thanks https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=554